# Problem with sorting list

Tags: sorting, .net-4.0

I have a problem with sorting collection. User saves few values  and he sorts it.

At next launch  program must order a new collection.

Values which have been saved by user can be in new collection, but It can be situation , when those values aren't in new collection.

I wrote some code, and I want your feedback If it has sense

```
var oldValues = new List<string>(new[] { "id5", "id3", "id1" });
var valuesToOrder = new List<string>(new[] { "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4" });

int numberOfReorderedValues = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < oldValues.Count; i++)
{
    if (valuesToOrder.Contains(oldValues[i]))
    {
         int indexOfValueWhichShouldBeBefore = valuesToOrder.IndexOf(oldValues[i]);
         string valueWhichShouldBeBefore = valuesToOrder[indexOfValueWhichShouldBeBefore];

         string valueWhichShouldBeAfter = valuesToOrder[numberOfReorderedValues];

         valuesToOrder[numberOfReorderedValues] = valueWhichShouldBeBefore;
         valuesToOrder[indexOfValueWhichShouldBeBefore] = valueWhichShouldBeAfter;


         numberOfReorderedValues++;
```

This code works, but I must tomorrow show it to my boss, and I don't go to fool

Comment: "Would" and "Should" can't come one right after the other in English, and shouldn't do that in code too. Select one.

Comment: I know, It was mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're after.

It sounds like you've got 2 lists. One of them contains a list of 'required', and the other contains a list of 'pick from'.

How about use LINQ to sort?

```
var oldValues = new List<string>(new[] { "id5", "id3", "id1" });
var valuesToOrder = new List<string>(new[] { "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4" });

var sorted = valuesToOrder.Intersect(oldValues).OrderBy(x=>x);

// sorted now has id1 and id3, sorted alphabetically.
```